# How to implement URL rewirting on Window server - IIS using PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis

Here is my `.htaccess` code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks    
RewriteEngine on

IndexIgnore *    
RewriteRule ^matrimony/([^/.]+)/?$ community-details.php?id=$1 [L]
```

My URL :

http://shaadichoice.com/matrimony/agarwal-matrimony

Answer (score 0):

Download the `IIS URL Rewrite 2.0` module and install it on your server. After installation don't forget to close and reopen the IIS Manager.

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Or if you already have [Web Platform Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) on your machine you can install the `IIS URL Rewrite 2.0` module from there.

Answer (score 0):

You should install URL Rewrite module.

In web.config file you should add this rule:

```
<rule name="rewriterulefromhtaccess">
    <match url="^matrimony/([^/.]+)/?$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="community-details.php?id={R:1}" />
</rule>
```